# I don't get any result when executing a SQL sentence where I use TRUNC in the WHERE clause in PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a table in an Oracle database called *reservation* that has a datetime column called *date_reservation*. And I have the following code:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberrows FROM reservation WHERE TRUNC(date_reservation)=TO_DATE('15/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')";
$stid = $this->bd->execute($sql);
$row = $this->bd->get_row($stid, 0);
echo $row['NUMBERROWS'];
```

The table content is:

```
ID    ...     DATE_RESERVATION
1             13/06/2015 12:00:00
2     ...     15/06/2015 09:00:00
3     ...     15/06/2015 11:00:00
```

When I execute my PHP code I get 0, and I should get 2.
But if I execute this sql sentence in my DB admin tool I get 2.

If I remove the WHERE CLAUSE from my code (`$sql = SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberrows FROM reservation`) I get the number of rows in the *reservation* table.

So I guess something is wrong with TRUNC in PHP. How could I solve it?

Comment: i would guess it has something to do with the date mask in PHP, i don't know PHP so can be of no more use than that

Comment: Solve it by not using trunc like that.  When you get lots of data it's very slow.  Instead, use where date >= yourdate and date < (yourdate + 1)

Comment: Can you double check your `date` column, both its name and data type?  `date` is a reserved keyword in Oracle. So if your column name really is `date`, or `DATE`, then you need to use it in double quotes to access it.  Something like `TRUNC("DATE")`, where the casing actually matters.  Though I would have expected you to get an error rather than a count of zero, but then I don't know if that's normal PHP behavior. I don't know PHP at all.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you miss a semicolumn at the line 1 :

```
$sql = SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberrows FROM reservation WHERE TRUNC(date)=TO_DATE('15/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
$stid = $this->bd->execute($sql);
$row = $this->bd->get_row($stid, 0);
echo $row['NUMBERROWS'];
```

Maybe it came from that? :)

Comment: I forgot to write the colons here, so that's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

You have colons missing in first line:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberrows FROM reservation WHERE TRUNC(date)=TO_DATE('15/06/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy')";
$stid = $this->bd->execute($sql);
$row = $this->bd->get_row($stid, 0);
echo $row['NUMBERROWS'];
```

Try this now. If you still did not get accurate results than check your date format that you are using in query.

Comment: I forgot to write the colons here. So that's not the problem. And the date format is correct

Answer (score -1):

The first thing you must pay attention,what comes from `trunc(date)`. Check the data in your `date` column, the format of date type must be exactly right with the format of `to_date('15/06/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')`

Comment: Untrue. A date column has no format. Formats apply when you re dealing with a string, not a date type.